# Using Yii2 GridView with array of data

Tags: php, yii2

I have an array:

```
$arr = ['ID' => 'A1', 'Description' => 'Item to be sold', ...]
```

In controller:

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
'allModels' => $arr,
//'sort' =>['attributes' => ['ID', 'Description'],],
'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 5]
]);
$this -> render('index', ['provider' => $arr]);
```

In view (`index.php`):

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $provider,
]);
```

And there is no result on page. Where it is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few errors in your code.

**1)** `$arr` should have the structure like this:

```
$arr = [
    ['ID' => 'A1', 'Description' => 'Item to be sold'],
    ...
],
```

**2)** In the `render` parameters you passed `$arr` instead of `$provider`, should be:

```
$this->render('index', ['provider' => $provider]);
```

**3)** You missed `return` statement before `render`:

```
return $this->render('index', ['provider' => $provider]);
```

Also I don't recommend using spaces around the arrow.

**4)** You did not specified any columns in `GridView`. You can add `ID` and `Description` like this:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'columns' => [
        'ID',
        'Description',
    ],
]);
```

**5)** And finally you are not echoing the GridView to the screen. Should be:

```
echo GridView::widget([...]);
```

or

```
<?= GridView::widget([...]) ?>
```

Comment: You are right, but how can you filter columns with the GridView ?

Comment: If you have another problem, please create the separate question for that. This problem is solved.